# A result on the minimum number of critical points of a Morse function

Tags: reference-request, symplectic-geometry, morse-theory

At 8:22 in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DVy0BcrWgFc&t=609s) the professor cites a result that, for a simply connected symplectic manifold of dimension at least 6, the minimum number of critical points of a Morse function is the sum of the Betti numbers. I could not find any reference to this result anywhere online. I would like to read more about it. Please help.

Comment: You don't need so many hypotheses. The point is that from a Morse function on a closed smooth manifold, it is homotopy equivalent to a CW complex with $k$-cells in bijection with index $k$ critical points. So there are as many critical points as cells in a particular cell decomposition, and you need at least as many cells as $\sum b_k$.

Comment: I think that the point is showing that the minimum is achieved.

Comment: This result is by Smale but he does not remember it :/

Comment: Well, that's not true. Let $g_k, r_k$ be the minimal possible number of generators and relators needed to express $H_k$. (For instance, for $\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z/2$, $g_k = 2$ and $r_k = 1$.) Then you need at least $g_k+r_{k-1}$ index $k$ critical points. But once you sum over $\sum g_k + r_{k-1}$, this *is* possible, and the handle-trading tricks are essentially the same as in Smale's proof of the h-cobordism theorem.